# BeautifulSoup select function works differently between Python3.5.2 and Python3.4.2

Tags: python, html, regex, select, beautifulsoup

**Problem:** I have a html file, it contains some tag, and now I want to find a tag(table) with a class attribute which value is 'targets', use BeautifulSoup4.5.1, it works fine in python3.5.2(Mac Sierra), but do not work in python3.4.2(raspberry pi), I want to figure out why.

Here is the example html file(test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="maincontainer">
    <tbody>
        <tr>中文</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="main">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="embedded">
                                <td></td>
                                <table class="targets"></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is how I write in the python file:

```
str=''
with open('test.html','rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    str=f.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(str)
table=soup.select('table[class="targets"]')
```

so can anyone tell me about these following questions:

- how select function work?
- why this does not work in 3.4.2 but work in 3.5.2?
- is there any answer to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the different modules installed in your 3.5 and 3.4 Python environments. When you don't pass a desired parser name explicitly:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str)
```

[*`BeautifulSoup` would pick the parser automatically*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) choosing from one of the installed modules. If you have `lxml` installed, it would pick it, if not, it would pick `html5lib` - if it is not installed, it would pick the built-in `html.parser`:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

In other words, you should be defining the parser explicitly to avoid any future related problems. Determine which one works for your particular case and set it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str, "html5lib")
# or soup = BeautifulSoup(str, "lxml")
# or soup = BeautifulSoup(str, "html.parser")
```